# Plot with matplotlib from .csv file containing duplicate column names

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, matplotlib, dataframe

I am plotting lines using the combined ID1 and ID2 columns. In the .csv file, the ID1 and ID2 numbers could be repeated at some point. The way to decide if the data needs to be a new line is directly following when ID2 = 0. I want the program to recognize the sample data I provided below as 2 separate lines.

```
ID1 ID2  x  y
1   2    1  1
1   2    2  2
1   2    3  3
1   2    4  4 
1   0    5  5
...
1   2    1  3
1   2    2  5
1   2    3  7
```

Right now, my program would plot this data as a continuous line in the same color. I need a new line in a different color, but I can't figure out how to filter the data to start a new line even when the ID1 and ID2 values are duplicates. The program needs to see the '0' in the ID2 column as a signal to start a new line. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to find out the indizes of the the zeros and loop over them to create individual DataFrames to plot.

```
u = u"""ID1 ID2  x  y
1   2    1  1
1   2    2  2
1   2    3  3
1   2    4  4 
1   0    5  5
1   2    1  3
1   2    2  5
1   2    3  7
1   0    1  3
1   2    2  4
1   2    3  2
1   2    4  1"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

inx = list(np.where(df["ID2"].values==0)[0]+1)
inx = [0] + inx + [len(df)]
for i in range(len(inx)-1):
    dff = df.iloc[inx[i]:inx[i+1],:]
    dff.plot(x="x", y="y", ax=ax, label="Label {}".format(i))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to use `cumsum` and `seaborn` plotting with `hue`:

```
temp_df = df.assign(line_no=df.ID2.eq(0).cumsum()).query('ID2 != 0')

import seaborn as sns
_ = sns.pointplot(x='x',y='y', hue='line_no',data=temp_df)
```

[image]

Or with matplotlib:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i in temp_df.line_no.unique():
    x=temp_df.query('line_no == @i')['x']
    y=temp_df.query('line_no == @i')['y']
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing the point (5,5), i.e. the point with the 0 in the ID2 column.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hrm... I though ID=0 was a "delimiter" for new line and shouldn't be plotted.  Either way.  Thanks.